# How to set several owners for a Google Drive folder?

Tags: google-drive, permissions, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-folder

Strangely enough, I couldn't find any information about this, which I would have thought is a common problem. I want to share a folder with another person I work with. I want to give them the same permissions as I have, not just edit. I want to make them owners of that folder.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only one person can own a folder in Google Drive.  You can allow access to other people, but there can be only one owner.

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494886

Comment: According to that, the editor can really do anything, ie. delete files. The person I work with has told me otherwise. So he must be wrong and the problem must be something else. Thanks

Comment: Yes, an editor can do everything but delete the folder or files owned by another person.

Comment: @tinym Important to note that someone with `Can edit` is able to `Remove` files from a shared folder which **revokes shared access for everyone except the owner of the removed document**. The owner can find the document by searching or looking through their `All Items` list.

Comment: It is however problematic if you want to send notifications to multiple people because it only allows you to send these notifications to the owner.

Comment: Even though you can't set multiple owners in the interface, the GDrive API for who owns a file is called "owners" and it's value is a list of just one user in all the files I've seen. So apparently they had planned on allowing multiple owners at one point or another.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner and wish also other people to be notified about new Google Forms that were filled in, it can be set up via the email forwarding option and creating of a filter. Go to *Mail* → *Settings* → *Forwarding*. There you can add the respective email addresses to forward and you can create a filter: use the name of the form and add it for the subject.